# Sync Linux directory with Windows network path

Tags: windows, batch-file, rsync, pscp

I have a scenario where I have to sync a Linux directory and a windows network path.

For now I'm doing this in two steps

1. pscp for copying the file from the Linux machine to my local windows machine.
2. xcopy for copying the file from my machine to the desired windows network path.

All I'm looking for here is is there a way to sycn the Linux directory with the windows network path.

Comment: Do you have any code yet? You need to give as much detail as possible if you want us to help solve a specific problem.

Comment: `pscp <username>@<servername>:<source file path> <destination path>`
`move "<source file path>" "<destination path>" /s`

Comment: I have this scheduled once a day.

Comment: What exactly do you want the sync to do, and in what direction?

Comment: I want to sync a directory in Linux server(source) with a Windows network path(destination).
And the direction is `Linux directory -> Windows Network path`

Comment: And by 'sync', I assume you want any files not present in the source (Linux side) to be deleted on the destination?

Comment: Not necessarily needed.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend you use WinSCP for this task. When using it as a GUI it's a great tool, but crucially, it can also be automated with ease. Here is [a formal guide on how automation works](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation) and here is a [tutorial video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ndvEYOQLc4c) showing how it works in practice with a batch file.

You basically want to copy what the guy in the video did, by making a script to log into your remote server and perform a local synchronization. Any other options, such as choosing to mirror, and how to compare existing files, can also be adjusted by looking at the docs.